# Hide textbox on export

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one textbox in SSRS report which I need to hide on export. I added expression for `Hidden` property to `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "RPL", True, False)`. but it always hiding textbox in ReportViewer as well as any type of export file.
Currently I have temporary fixed using <s>`= IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive OrElse Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "MHTML", False, True)`</s> 

but wondering Why the first expression not working?
and what is the solution for it?

**Edit**: `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` working. Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "MHTML" is not working so main statement stricked out in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not explicitely detailed in the documentation. `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` is only accessible during different parts of the processing and rendering cycle.

On the other hand `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` is populated before the render request, hence before the Hidden property expression of your textbox is evaluated.

Check these links:

[REFERENCE 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx#Anchor_0)

[REFERENCE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175275/2647648)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What could be solution of it? I mean hiding the text box for any export. Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive returns true even for MHTML.

Comment: @par, If you want to hide the textbox in any case, what is the purpose of use Global variables?

Comment: alejandro zuleta , I mean hiding the textbox in any type of export, in report viewer it should be visible.

Comment: @par, The only option you have is use `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` but MHTML is interactive. Also a hard way could be customize programmatically Report Viewer export options.