# SSRS Export to MHTML is not displaying Element based on Visibility Settings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

In SSRS, the logo has been displayed with the help of external image resource. The visibility settings are handled by expression as like below

```
Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive
```

Since we don't want to see the logo on Report Viewer Control and just want this on exporting into Excel/work/PDF/MHTML. The problem with MTHML is RenderFormat.IsInteractive is true because of that the logo is not visible in exported document.

Tried with some workaround provided in internet not helped US
Workaround# 1 for Hidden Property

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="MHTML",IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,False,True),IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,True,False))
```

Workaround# 2 for Hidden Property

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF" ,IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,False,True),
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="WORDOPENXML" ,IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,False,True),
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML" ,IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,False,True),
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,True,False))))
```

Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can't you just add another **IIF** for the MTHML? ... IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML",  IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,False,True),  **IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="MTHML" , False,** IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,True,False))))

Comment: Yes I tried that well and it is not resolving the issue

Comment: I think that maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245561/ssrs-2008-r2-globalsrenderformat-export-methods

Comment: The given link is not helped to resolve the issue. Still on export to MHTML the logo is not displaying